# Linq Help for List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of object type `A`. I was wondering if I can create another collection, comprising of sub sets of `A`, such that `if A[i].Something == 'a' && A[i+1].Something == 'b'`, then add it to new collection.

The new collection would be a List of `KeyValue` pairs such that `(Key = A[i], Value = A[i+1])`

I wanted to accomplish this using lambda exp. Could someone guide me ?

Comment: Can you please add the current code that you are using

Comment: it's a litte confusing. So you have f.e. `List<A> collection` what exactly do you mean by subsets of `A`? do you mean a subset of the collection? or do you want to split the type of objects that the collection holds?

Comment: hi Mong. I wanted a subset of A, comprising of elements which satisfy the mentioned code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since standard *Linq* *doesn't support* `Lead` (`Lag`) methods (have a look at [More Linq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) if you insist on Linq-like solution), I suggest implementing a simple generator:

```
private static IEnumerable<KeyValue<MyClass, MyClass>> MakePairs(
  IEnumerable<MyClass> source) {

  if (null == source)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

  MyClass prior = default(MyClass);
  bool first = true;

  foreach (var current in source) {
    if (first) {
      prior = current;
      first = false;

      continue;
    }

    if (prior != null && current != null && 
        prior.Something == "A" && current.Something == "B") //TODO: put right condition 
      yield return new KeyValue(prior, current);

    prior = current;
  }   
}

...

IEnumerable<MyClass> source = ... 

var result = MakePairs(source).ToList();
```

Comment: What do you think about `prior = source.FirstOrDefault();` and then `foreach (var current in source.Skip(1))`? That would make the `if` redundant

Comment: @Default: in case of `source.FirstOrDefault()` and then `foreach` you scan collection *twice* (even if the 1st scan is one item only). It may be an *issue* if 1. Collection opening is *expensive* (e.g. we have a file, RDBMS query etc.) 2. If Collection is mutable (say, someone's changed the file right in between `FirstOrDefault()` and `foreach`). When collection's origin is *unknown*, scan it *once*

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get the key/value pairs is to zip the collection with all items except the first. Should theoretically work on any enumerable which preserves order. If 'coll' is your source:

```
coll.Zip(coll.Skip(1), (a1,a2) => new {Key = a1.Something, Value = a2.Something})
```

To get only for values 'a' and 'b':

```
coll.Zip(coll.Skip(1), (a1,a2) => new {Key = a1.Something, Value = a2.Something})
        .Where(kv=>kv.Key == "a" && kv.Value == "b")
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
IEnumerable<string> list;
IEnumerable<string> list2 = list.Skip(1);

string test1 = "a";
string test2 = "b";

var result = list
  .Zip(list.Skip(1), 
       (x, y) => Tuple.Create(x, y))
  .Where(r => r.Item1 == test1 && r.Item2 == test2)
  .ToDictionary(r => r.Item1, 
                r => r.Item2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Select`, which has an overload to get the index, which is useful in this case to retrieve the next item in your list.

```
var newCollection = collection.Select
                               ( (a, i) => new
                                    { A = a
                                    , NextA = (i + 1) < collection.Length ? collection[i + 1] : null
                                    }
                               );
```

From there on you can write the predicate you want:

```
var filteredCollection = newCollection.Where
                                       (x => x.A.Something == "a"
                                             && x.NextA?.Something == "b"
                                       );
```

Answer (score 0):

OP has a collection so I started out with an ICollection:

```
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<A, A>> KeyValueSelecting(ICollection<A> source) {
        if (null == source) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source)); }
        for (var i = 0; i < source.Count - 1; i++) {
            var firstElement = source.ElementAtOrDefault(i);
            if (firstElement?.Something != "A") { yield break; }
            var seceondElement = source.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1);
            if (seceondElement?.Something != "B") { yield break; }
            yield return new KeyValuePair<A, A>(firstElement, seceondElement);
        }
    }
```